# Get friends of an user

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

An user X joined my application but he is not my friend, so I would like to see his friends, write in their walls, etc. Is it possible using the REST API?

Also, is possible to send a friend request to some user using the API?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you could using the REST API: target_id.

```
 "This mimics the action of posting on a friend's Wall on Facebook itself." 
 - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/
```

However, I think, for new applications, you'd better use not-deprecated methods.